# Does everyone get equal chance

Tags: belief, life, judgements

I believe our life is just a test. in a test everyone should've equal chance to make it equitable. I know everyone have different types of test depending on their living condition but some people die very young, some lives long. If there is a bad person who died at young age and another bad person who lives long to become a good person then how this gonna be fair. Also some kids die young who don't get tested as long as someone old to go through all the bad attractions of this world.

I know Allah is the only one who can be real judge. even though I'm having this question I'm not questioning Allah I know it's just my limitation so iam seeking help from those have knowledge

Comment: Just know that Allah is aware of what struggles each and every person goes through, what society they were brought up in, their intentions etc and the person will probably be punished/rewarded accordingly.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 0):

Every human being created by God will always be given a chance, a test or a temporary problem in the world. Everyone has their own problems, Allah tests them with different tests but the reason is the same.

Allah is testing a person because He has His own secrets, whether He wants to increase our faith or to test our faith. It may be that some of our friends or relatives of ours are facing the same fate or worse than us. However, hasn't Allah made it clear in the Qur'an that He will never test His servants beyond the ability of His servants.

To answer your question, equability chances in every person is subjective. Sometimes, the person may seem to be very unlucky in his/her life. But Allah knows best on what suits to the person. Thus, the chances we see might not be same to other human beings, but it is enough for him/her to have faith in Allah.

May we always be pleased with the trials and conditions of Allah Almighty. What has been set for us is the best.

Wallahualam.